# use jQuery to replace one tag with another, keeping all attributes & data

Tags: jquery

I realise this is similar to [Using jQuery to replace one tag with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093417/using-jquery-to-replace-one-tag-with-another), however I'm looking to replace a tag with another tag inside html, but KEEP the attributes and any defined custom data (set via $.data) for the object. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the tag but keep the attributes and content -- jQuery/Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665820/change-the-tag-but-keep-the-attributes-and-content-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Which tags concretely? Why don't you edit the HTML source instead? I'm asking because what you want seems like an awful approach.

Comment: where is your sample html?

Comment: @Explosion Pills - That other question is not a duplicate, because it doesn't cover keeping values stored with `.data()`. frumbert - do you also want to keep event handlers?

Answer (score 0):

Copying the attributes shouldn't be too hard, this answer focuses on retaining the data and events that are attached to a node.

When you write `$('#myid').data('msg', 'hello world')`, internally jQuery creates a special property onto the DOM element called `jQuery.expando` (which is just a string that starts with `"jQuery"` and followed by a bunch of numbers). The value of that property holds a key to the `jQuery.cache` array, which is where your custom data and event handlers are stored in.

```
// lets assume you want to replace node a with node b
// we need the DOM elements for this
var nodea = ..., nodeb = ...;

// jQuery data references are stored in a special property of the node
var key = nodea[jQuery.expando], 
cache = jQuery.cache[key];

// perform replacement
$(nodea).replaceWith(nodeb);

if (cache) {
  // restore data
  jQuery.cache[key] = cache;
  nodeb[jQuery.expando] = key;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/onerok/1/)

You should use this at your own risk though; messing with internals is often not the best solution.