# Change HTML tags, including children of same tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I'm using this [previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665820/change-the-tag-but-keep-the-attributes-and-content-jquery-javascript) about altering an HTML tag and while trying to update some HTML tags, I'm having trouble reaching the tags within a parent of the same tag.

For example, updating a span to a div should result in:

```
<div>
    <div>div within a div</div>
</div>
```

But is showing up like:

```
<div>
    <span>div within a div</span>
</div>
```

And for reference, this is the js:

```
var divTag = 'div';

$('span').each(function() {
    var outer = this.outerHTML;

    // Replace all span tags with the type of divTag
    var regex = new RegExp('<' + this.tagName, 'i');
    var newTag = outer.replace(regex, '<' + divTag);

    // Replace closing tag
    regex = new RegExp('</' + this.tagName + '>$', 'i');
    newTag = newTag.replace(regex, '</' + divTag + '>');

    $(this).replaceWith(newTag);
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little transformation in @guest271314 solution, to avoid replace the content, only replace the HTML tags.

```
var div = $("div");
var html = div[0].outerHTML.replace(/<div/g, "<span");
div.replaceWith(html);
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/31c5bebx/1/

**EDIT:**

```
$("div").each(function(){
    var html = $(this)[0].outerHTML.replace(/<div/g, "<span");
    $(this).replaceWith(html);
});
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/31c5bebx/5/

Comment: One issue I'm noticing is if you're updating something like a <p> or an <h1> its pulling the inner html and duplicating that as well. see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/31c5bebx/3/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var div = $("div");
var html = div[0].outerHTML.replace(/div(?=>)/gi, "span");
console.log(html);
div.replaceWith(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
    <div>div within a div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Imgonzalves jQuery not appear loaded at https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/Lmquhnno/ ; see https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/Lmquhnno/1/

Comment: Yes you are rigth, my fault.