# Using JQUERY to change tag "a" for "span" keeping content

Tags: jquery

I am using JQUERY to change "a" to "span" but without success.

```
 $('table a').replaceWith(function() {
       return $("<span>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");
    });
```

My question is: How can I change the tag "a" to "span" but keeping the content?

I have:

```
<td style="">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
        data-name="id" 
        data-pk="1" 
        data-value="01A001" 
        data-url="./save.php">My ID</a>
</td>
```

I want to have:

```
  <td style="">
         <span href="javascript:void(0)" 
            data-name="id" 
            data-pk="1" 
            data-value="01A001" 
            data-url="./save.php">My ID</span>
    </td>
```

Thank you ALL.

Comment: `href` is an invalid attribute for a `<span>` tag.

Comment: Thank you David, I know, but first I need to know how to change the A to SPAN.

Comment: Or [Change the tag but keep the attributes and content — jQuery/Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665820/change-the-tag-but-keep-the-attributes-and-content-jquery-javascript)

Comment: When you find yourself needing to do things like this, it is helpful to rethink everything. Not sure why you'd need to add, for instance an `href` to a span. Maybe you asked the wrong question. Here is an equally bad answer (that does what you want): [link](https://jsfiddle.net/f80gw3fh/3/)